# Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: 'Code: BadRequest Message: Operation not supported for this Channel

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, microsoft-api

Я использую эту документацию - https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/graph/api/channel-post-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp%2Chttp.

Получаю это сообщение, когда я хочу добавить нового участника в канал [![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]

```
 var conversationMember = new AadUserConversationMember
            {
                Roles = new List<String>()
                {

                },
                AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
                {
                    {userBind, $"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('{userId}')"}
                }
            };

            await graphClient.Teams[$"{teamId}"].Channels[$"{channelId}"].Members
                .Request()
                .AddAsync(conversationMember); //Здесь получаю ошибку
```

Создаю канал тут

```
var team = new Team
            {
                DisplayName = department.Name,
                Channels = new TeamChannelsCollectionPage()
                {

                },
                Members = new TeamMembersCollectionPage()
                {
                    new AadUserConversationMember
                    {
                        Roles = new List<String>()
                        {
                            "owner"
                        },
                        AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
                        {
                            { userBind, $"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('{ownerId}')" }
                        },
                    }
                },

                AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
                {
                    { templateBind, urlTeamsApiStandard },
                }
            };

            foreach (var bitrixChannel in department.Channels)
            {
                var channel = new Channel
                {
                    DisplayName = bitrixChannel.Name,
                    MembershipType = ChannelMembershipType.Private
                };

                team.Channels.Add(channel);
            }

            await graphClient.Teams
                     .Request()
                     .AddAsync(team);
```

Что не так?

**UPD**

Я понял что мои каналы в MS Teams не создаются в приватном режиме, хотя я указываю это, но не могу понять почему это не работает
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Tcdk.png

Answer (score 0):

Я понял, что надо использовать такую конструкцию

```
await graphClient.Teams[teamId].Channels
                 .Request()
                     .AddAsync(channel);
```